# Does somebody know if my beginner (dice game) code correct is and where to start to make a dice game?

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error

Here is the code:

```
from random import randint
def random_number():
    random_num = randint(range(1,7))
    for i in random_num:
        enter = int(raw_input("Enter a nunber: "))
        if random_num == enter:
            print "Congratulations, You Win!!!"
        elif random_num != enter:
            print "That's not the correct answer!"
        else:
            print "That's not a valid number!"
```

For some reason I can't test my code (it pops cmd out and that's it). Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: First I would call random_number() if you wanted to test the function.

Comment: If you're just asking for help on why your code just pops up a cmd window and quits, please change your title to match your question. If you're asking for something bigger, please explain exactly what you're asking in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

replace :

```
 random_num = randint(range(1,7))
```

to:

```
 random_num = randint(1,7)
```

and also:

for i in range(1,7):

```
from random import randint
def random_number():
    random_num = randint(1,7)
        for i in range(1,7):
            enter = int(raw_input("Enter a nunber: "))
            if type(enter) == int:
                if random_num == enter:
                    print "Congratulations, You Win!!!"
                    break
                else:print "wrong guess"
            else:print "That's not a valid number!"
```

random_number()

`range` will give the list of number from start to end-1, if ony end is given, it will take '0' as starting point. `randint` will give you a random no between specified range

 why your cmd pop and go out, you haven't called your function you defined `random_number` you need to call the function like i did in edited code

Comment: What about the IndentationError?

Comment: This doesn't solve the main problem he's asking about—unless you actually call `random_number()` somewhere it doesn't matter how perfect you get it. Also, there are other problems here beyond the ones you've fixed. For example, there's no way `random_num == enter` and `random_num != enter` can both be false; I think he's expecting that if you enter `sjhfds`, you'll end up with a magic value instead of an exception.

Comment: yep right,i just fixed the indentation error and range thing

Comment: @Hackaholic: Yes, his code is poorly written, and he's asking you to fix it. You can either fix it so it actually works, or (better) just tell him that's not what SO is for. Fixing half of his problems while leaving the rest (including the one he's specifically asking about) doesn't really answr him.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason I can't test my code (it pops cmd out and that's it). Can somebody help me with that?

You create a function, `random_number`, but you never *call* that function. So, when you run your script, it just defines that function, then, with nothing else it do, it quits.

To fix that, just add a line to the end of the script that calls it:

```
random_number()
```

---

You also have this more general two-in-one question:

> Does somebody know if my beginner (dice game) code correct is and where to start to make a dice game?

It's not correct. In fact, there are multiple things wrong with it, and more things that are technically OK but strange. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a debugging service. If you have a specific question, you can ask that and get an answer, but not just "make my code work".

As for where to start… well, you've already started in the right place. You're simulating the roll of a (7-sided) die, you're interacting with the user… that's a dice game, right? You just need to debug it now.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windows, simply use your terminal, cd to the directory and execute the code with "python filename.py" where filename is your python code's file name. This will work if python has been installed as in your system variables. (default when installing)

Else, you should change :

```
random_num = randint(range(1,7))
```

to

```
random_num = randint(1,7)
```

and also remove

```
for i in random_num:
```

your code should work, but the two other conditions are kind of useless.
you should use somthing like

```
enter.isdigit()
```

to know if the user entered a number.

plus,

```
enter < 7 and enter > 0
```

To make sure that the number the user entered is in the valid range.

You should use a IDE to work, it would be a lot easier!

Edit :
Here, I would have done something like this :

```
from random import randint
def random_number():
    random_num = randint(1,7)
    while True:
        enter = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        if enter.isdigit():
            if int(enter)<7 and int(enter)>0:
                if random_num == int(enter):
                    print "Congratulations, You Win!!!"
                    break
                elif random_num != int(enter):
                    print "That's not the correct answer!"
                    break
            else:
                print "That's not a valid number!"            
        else:
            print "That's not even a number!"

random_number()
```

Comment: y douple bracket in randint, only one is enough

Comment: `enter.isdigit()` is not a good way to check whether `enter` can be converted to `int`. It's not true for negative numbers; it is true for non-English digits that aren't convertible to `int`; etc. Also, calling `int(enter)` all over the place is a big DRY violation; it's very easy to forget one of those `int(…)` calls and have a painful-to-track-down bug because 3 and `"3"` aren't equal. Also, that `<7` check that you've added makes the game unwinnable 14% of the time. Finally, you're only giving them 1 chance to guess, while he gave them 7, making the game much harder.